# Neural network: same prediction for different inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am getting the same prediction for different inputs. I am trying to use a regressional neural network. I want to predict values instead of class using neural network. Since data is huge, I am training one example at a time. Here is a simplified version of my code.

```
list_of_files= Path().cwd().glob("**/**/*S1D_A.fits") # create the list of file
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10000, input_dim=212207, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
for file_name in list_of_files:
    data=fits.getdata(file_name)
    X=data.flux 
    Y=data.rv
    #X is one input example with 212207 values/features
    #Y is one output value (float) 
    if i<6000000:         #out of 10000000
        model.fit(X.transpose(), Y, epochs=30, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
    else:
        prediction=model.predict(X.transpose())
```

I made sure that I am training on different examples and trying predictions on different examples. I am still getting the same prediction value for all testing inputs. I tried a smaller input space instead of 212207 for debugging, but that did not help. The dataset is balanced and shuffled. Values of inputs range from 0 to 0.1 million. I haven't normalised them. values of output vary from -30 to 0.
I think I made some mistake in defining the model for regression neural network.  Can you please check if the code is correct?

Comment: Rest of the world does not measure anything in "lakh". So please don't use Indian words / measurements here.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data to test with?

Comment: You are training your model 6 * 30 million times on the entire dataset and then testing the same model on the same set for 4 million times. Don't you think the model will overfit?

Comment: There are 212207 input features and two hidden layers. In each iteration in for loop, I am reading input from a different file. similarly for output. I am trying to train on one example at a time. so a total of 6 million different training examples and 4 million different testing examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to pass each record from dataset instead of whole dataset. Right now you predict on exactly same data as you train.

This is what you want to execute:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10000, input_dim=212207, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

X = X.transpose()

# train
model.fit(X[:6000000], Y, epochs=30, batch_size=1, verbose=0)

# test
prediction=model.predict(X[6000000:])
```

Comment: In each iteration, I am reading input from a different file. similarly for output. I am trying to train on one example at a time. so a total of 6 million different training examples and 4 million different testing examples.

Comment: Yeah but take a look that every time you use X.transpose() in model.fit, so you are passing whole dataset, not just one record :)

Comment: I want to train on one example at a time. So, how should I change my code to train one example at a time? should I replace .fit(...) with .train_on_batch(...)?

Comment: No, I will update answer for you :)

Comment: Oh no no no. X is NOT the whole dataset. My whole dataset is 315Gb which has to be collected from multiple files. X is one input example.  I just changed the code to better reflect that. Because ram cannot hold 315GB of data at a time I am training one example at a time.